# How to upsert in a mongodb nested object without losing existing unreferenced fields

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm using C# in dot net to create and update simple collections in mongodb (I'm new to nosql having done only mysql). Creation is no problem, and neither is updating for the most part. But I have a nested object that on update will likely contain existing fields. If the request does not use those fields, only the referenced fields i.e. those to insert or update will be added- the existing ones are lost.

Searched for similar problems on here but found nothing quite matching. Some references to methods AddToSet and AddToSetEach, but don't think they are quite appropriate here.

Found mentions of fetching the existing document first and updating that, but figured that could get messy and that this must be a common problem with a straight-forward solution.

Code for updationg (abridged) is very simple really:

```
public class Issue {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public IDictionary<string, string> Properties { get; set; }
        public string AssignedToUserId { get; set; }
    }

var issue = new Issue {
                    Id = "MEC0eNrSQk2ZhDJnZ3f36g",
                    AssignedToUserId = "someuserid",
                    Properties = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        { "prop2", "ghj" },
                        { "prop3", "xyz" }
                    };
}

var update = Builders<Issue>.Update
                .Set(x => x.AssignedToUserId, issue.AssignedToUserId)
                .Set(x => x.Properties, issue.Properties);

await _mongoDb.UpdateOneAsync(Builders<Issue>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, issue.Id), update);
```

```
Document on creation (abridged):
{
"_id" : "MEC0eNrSQk2ZhDJnZ3f36g",
"Properties" : {
    "prop1" : "abc",
    "prop2" : "def"
},
"AssignedToUserId" : null
}
```

I wish to update the properties object by:
Changing the value of `prop2` to `ghj`
adding a new field `prop3` with some arbitrary value
[and leave prop1 the hell alone!]

The result (abridged to only show properties object)

```
  "Properties" : {
   "prop2" : "ghj"
   "prop3" : "xyz"
   }
```

So the new property was added, the existing property I wanted changing was changed ok, but `prop1` is lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to issue an update command with `$set` operator. your props can be targeted with their names using dotted path as follows:

```java
db.Issue.update({
    "_id": ObjectId("5d2fd8e820f6a5274823cbee")
}, {
    "$set": {
        "Properties.prop2": "geh",
        "Properties.prop3": "xyz"
    }
})
```

here's the c# code that generated the above query. it's using my library MongoDB.Entities for brevity.

```cs
using MongoDB.Entities;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class Issue : Entity
        {
            public IDictionary<string, string> Properties { get; set; }
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test");

            var issue = new Issue
            {
                Properties = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        { "prop1", "abc" },
                        { "prop2", "def" }
                    }
            };
            issue.Save();

            DB.Update<Issue>()
              .Match(i => i.ID == issue.ID)
              .Modify(i => i.Properties["prop2"], "geh")
              .Modify(i => i.Properties["prop3"], "xyz")
              .Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found my own (embarrassingly simple) solution, and am not sure I would be able to implement yours (the update requests and mongo db code are divided by REST and client libraries). However, I'm happy to accept this solution as your mention of targeting the properties directly directly helped me realise my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I probably shouldn't answer my own question, but as I eventually came up with the solution and as it's embarrassingly simple, I'll post it (I'll also credit Ryan Gunner with accepted answer for reasons I'll explain in a comment on his answer).

```
//update = update.Set(x => x.Properties, issue.Properties)

foreach (var props in issue.Properties)
{
    update = update.Set(x => x.Properties[props.Key], props.Value);
}
```

Yes, that simple. As I said in my question I'd thought I needed to pull the issue and compare properties of that object and the update object line by line to do what I wanted. Either that or some magic method I wasn't familiar with.